# Image Not Being Found

Tags: c++, sfml

When I'm trying to display an image in SFML 2.0 it can never find the image. I'm using Visual Studio Express C++ 2010. Here's my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
 {
     // Create the main window
     sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

     // Load a sprite to display
     sf::Texture texture;
     if (!texture.loadFromFile("image.png"))
     {
         cout << "Could not find file image.png" << endl;
         system("PAUSE");
     }
     sf::Sprite sprite(texture);

     // Create a graphical text to display


     // Load a music to play

     // Start the game loop
     while (window.isOpen())
     {
         // Process events
         sf::Event event;
         while (window.pollEvent(event))
         {
             // Close window : exit
             if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                 window.close();
         }

         // Clear screen
         window.clear();

         // Draw the sprite
         window.draw(sprite);

         // Draw the string

         // Update the window
         window.display();
     }

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

But when I change the image directory to the specific "C:\Users\Chase\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Boonce\image.png" it works. Where do I need to put the image.png for it to display without the specific. I heard people say the working directory which I have no idea what it is. If it's th project folder ( Projects\Boonce\ ) then I already tried that, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be placed in the same directory as the `.exe` file or depending on your project settings in some other directory, perhaps the project directory.

Comment: Alright, that worked only when I launched the .exe , but when I run my project from VS, the image isn't found.

Comment: I believe that's because the exe visual studio uses is in a different directory (if you're using a different build setting from the one you're launching). Try either in the Debug or Release directories.

Comment: I'm currently running it through release and I put the image in the release directory.

Comment: I actually searched through VS and found the work directory location and placed the image in there and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2193568 Then it might be in the project directory itself. Alright, glad I could help. Upvote/mark as answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you need to set your ***working directory***

Go to:

- Project
- (*projectName*) properties
- Debugging
- Working Directory

And set the path to where your asset directory is.

The default is **$(ProjectDir)**, the directory in which your *.vcproj* file resides.